# sh.exe.'express' command still not found after correctly set PATH variables

Tags: windows, node.js, express, windows-7, npm

I'm using Windows 7 Ulitmate 64-Bit, I have re-installed node.js and Please don't tell me to reboot because, I've done it like thousand times.

The guides I found told me to install it by:

```
npm install express -g
```

You also need to install the express-generator:

```
npm install express-generator@4 -g
```

I even have set the paths correctly

https://i.stack.imgur.com/DYPr8.png

I read in other questions that spaces are not allowed; So, I have made their paths into variables.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3UoXk.png

I've been figuring out, what kind of bullshit is going on?! I've been pulling my hair out of frustration. My question is, What have I done wrong?

Comment: are you able to access node console, via typing `node` to `dos`?

Answer (score 1):

npm install -g express
then:
npm install -g express-generator  (without the @4)
worked fine for me.
No path change needed.